# Bokeh defocus not working on certain frames

Tags: animation, compositing-nodes

I'm currently working on a short animation (Blender 2.69 r60995) for an expo and i'm having a problem with bokeh defocus that it isn't composition on some frames, here's a gif clip:

[image: Bokh not working on every frame]

As you can see, the defocus is working right, but certain frames don't get composited (the compositing pass doesn't even show up).

Here are my compositing nodes:

[image: Blender nodes]

I have toggled "Use Z-Buffer" several times and the fStop, also tried not to use the Z-Buffer, and the problem is always the same, certain frames don't get rendered.

EDIT: Here's the defocus keyframe graph.

[image]

Comment: I see that there is some keyframe(s) on the "Max Blur" parameter (it's green). Are you sure this value is not at 0 for the concerned frame ?

Comment: Indeed the blur is animated and it got only 2 keyframes: One at the beginning when nothing is blurred and another one when the camera zooms in to the subject and defocus everything else. There are no extra keyframes.

Comment: OK, and I saw on your GIF that it was frames 3, 6 and 13 that are not blured. Quite strange. Did you tried disabling the Max Blur animation, and fix it to 8.0 (just to see if it works well) ? Oh, and another thing: is it every time the same frames that are not computed ?

Comment: The weird thing is that i have another scene with perfect bokeh defocus. Will check if removing the animation works.

Comment: Looks like it was that issue. Thanks Polosson.

Comment: Can you answer your question ? Please explain how your resolved the issue in detail. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed some changes to the defocus node on [developer.blender.org](http://developer.blender.org/rBbc6ba9eb3bf8c8560d5c0dd6eb9075325190fee7) yesterday. Can you try with an updated build and see if the problem persists?

Comment: I'm going to try, because the problem has persisted. Will report back when done testing. Although the diff is an angle related thing :-(

Comment: If this has been resolved, please post the solution as an answer to get this off of the unanswered list.

Comment: No, it wasn't answered, i went along with the horrible bokeh jumping... the event for what this was intended flopped, so it was a non-issue.